# Data Extract vs Query Activity

Tags: marketing-cloud, query

Can I ask what's the difference between a Data Extract Activity vs Query Activity?

I've created some Queries and realized that some information (like OS and Platform) was not available in Query Activity.

Edit: I am trying to extract ALL jobs sent with MC and currently I am getting the data from Data Extract Activity with the Click and SendJobs file.

I would like to customise the column of the output file and join them together into 1 file instead of having to download both the Click and SendJobs.

Hence I was exploring the Query function.

Thanks.

Comment: When you query a Salesforce Object, how would it know what Platform or OS you're querying it from? What you're referring to is related to the tool you're using to perform the data export or "extraction".

Answer (score 1):

A [**Query Activity**](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/) is for selecting rows from a [**Data Extension**](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/subscribers/data_extensions_for_exacttarget_marketing_cloud/) or System Data View and writing them to another Data Extension.

A [**Data Extract Activity**](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/data_extract_activity/) is for extracting data out of the Marketing Cloud.

The syntax for SFMC Query Activities is closely related to [**Microsoft's Transact-SQL**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transact-SQL) (aka T-SQL).

Comment: Thanks Adam for your answer. Can I ask if we could "write a query" on Data Extract Activity to customised which column to extract?

Comment: It doesn't really work that way.  You can name the columns in the target Data Extension.  You can use aliases your Query Activity to match the columns.